# getRestrictions()->removeByType don't remove the restriction

Tags: backend, extbase, typo3-10.x

I want to select pages from database by their slug. For visible pages all works fine. But I can't select hidden pages. Then I tried to remove the HiddenRestriction but this did'nt work either.

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('pages'); 
$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeByType(HiddenRestriction::class);
$result = $queryBuilder->select('uid')->from('pages')->where("slug='".$slug."'")->execute();
```

I does only work with

`$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll();`

But then it will also find deleted pages.

Trying this

`$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll()->add(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DeletedRestriction::class));`

results in

`Oops, an error occurred! Class 'MyExt\UF\DeletedRestriction' not found`

Both lines of code are direct from Typo3 documentation, so I can't figure out the problem. Why does RemoveByType not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem for both issues, fo it is the same reason. The examples of documentation are not complete. In order to work properly you have to add the corresponding workspaces secondary.

In case of removeByType():

`use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\HiddenRestriction;`

and in case of add():

`use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\DeletedRestriction;`

Small cause, large effect....